Как создать свой собственный фильтр на основе класса UpdateFiler в python-telegram-bot 21.4?
Столкнулся с проблемой во время перехода на эту библиотеку: нужен фильтр, который будет говорить есть ли "текст" в update.callback.data.
Не могу понять как орудовать UpdateFilter и MessageFilter, откуда они берут обновления или сообщения, если эти аргументы не вводятся в класс или метод.
Буду благодарен за любой гайд, ссылочку или кусок кода
from telegram.ext import filters
class TextInMessage(filters.UpdateFilter):
    pass

